Could someone please give me some intution for this result for testing uniform convergence using Cauchy sequences?
In class, we proved this following result for testing for uniform convergence of a sequence of functions without much elaboration:
Theorem. A sequence of function $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent iff:

If $x_n\to x$ with $(x_n)\subseteq D\subseteq\mathbb R$ and $x\in \mathbb R$, then $f_n(x_n)\to f(x)$.

Could someone please give me an example or two illustrating how to use / in what situations this definition could be useful over, say, the standard "Challenge-response" definition of uniform convergence via the supremum norm of the difference, i.e., $$\forall \epsilon >0 \,\exists n_\epsilon \in \mathbb N \;s.t.\;\|f_n(x)-f(x)\|<\epsilon \quad\text{for all } x\in D$$
I've been thinking that this could potentially be useful to show that a sequence $(f_n)_{n≥1}$ does not converge uniformly. That is, taking the contrapositive, I can see that a potentially useful consequence is that if $f_n(x_n)\not\to f(x)$, then the convergence cannot be uniform if $f_n(x)$ happened to be of a form where I could simplify it algebraically by picking some $x_n=g(n)$ carefully.

Are you sure that theorem is complete as is? Without any assumptions on $f$ it can't be right.

Apologies, I forgot to add the uniform convergence part
